# Django AssertionError at url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

While learning Django rest framework, I got a **AssertionError at /tasks/1** error

**Expected view TaskDetail to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.**

My model.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    owner=models.ForeignKey('auth.User',related_name='tasks')
    completed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description=models.TextField()
```

serializer.py

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Task
    read_only=('owner.username',)
    fields=('title','description','completed','owner.username')
```

permission.py

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method is SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.owner==request.user
```

views.py

```
class TasksMixins(object):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class=TaskSerializer
    permission_classes=(IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def pre_save(self,obj):
        obj.owner=self.request.user

class TaskList(TasksMixins,ListCreateAPIView):
    pass

class TaskDetail(TasksMixins,RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    pass
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^tasks/$', views.TaskList.as_view(), name='task_list'),
    url(r'^tasks/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', views.TaskDetail.as_view(), name='task_detail')
]
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amogh/PycharmProjects/env_1.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/amogh/PycharmProjects/env_1.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/amogh/PycharmProjects/env_1.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amogh/PycharmProjects/env_1.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amogh/PycharmProjects/env_1.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/amogh/PycharmProjects/env_1.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amogh/PycharmProjects/env_1.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 286, in get
    return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amogh/PycharmProjects/env_1.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 56, in retrieve
    instance = self.get_object()
  File "/home/amogh/PycharmProjects/env_1.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 93, in get_object
    (self.__class__.__name__, lookup_url_kwarg)
AssertionError: Expected view TaskDetail to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
```

When ever I navigate to the link I get this error

Any help is much appreciated...Thanks in advace

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO4Qt.png)

Comment: In `urls.py`, line 4, change `<id>` to `<pk>`. You're passing a `pk` kwarg, but the url is expecting an `id` kwarg. It's Django convention to use pk rather than id.

Comment: @Bjorn....Thanks for reply...but getting **Field name `owner.username` is not valid for model `Task`.** error

Comment: Because it's not a `Task` field. See the field's source argument for that one

Answer (score 3):

If you want to target by 'pk', just rename id -> pk into your url.py:

`url(r'^tasks/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.TaskDetail.as_view(), name='task_detail')`

If you want to target by other field than pk,, you have to adjust the url.py, the view.py AND the serializer.py precising a lookup_field (that can be Nested) for example, it could be for you.

url.py:

```
url(r'^tasks/(?P<owner__username>[0-9]+)$', views.TaskDetail.as_view(), name='task_detail')
```

view.py:

```
class TasksMixins(object):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class=TaskSerializer
    permission_classes=(IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_field = 'owner__username'
```

serializer.py

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username',many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields='__all__'
        lookup_field = 'owner__username'
```